# Changing default value of a property of a control (DataGridView)

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, visual-studio

I am inheriting my own `DataGridView` (say **MyDataGridView**) from the standard `DataGridView` control. What I want is that certain properties of **MyDataGridView** should have a different default value than what its base have. For example, `AllowUserToAddRows`, `AllowUserToDeleteRows`, `AllowUserToResizeRows` properties should have the default values of `False`; so that when I drag **MyDataGridView** into a form in the IDE, the default values shown in the properties grid should be `False`. Later on, if I want to change them to `True` from the grid, they will be set accordingly.

Is it possible somehow?

Please note that I don't want to set the default value of any custom property in **MyDataGridView** but the properties mentioned 
above that are derived from the base.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy this class if you need it!

```
public class CustomGridView : DataGridView
{
    [DefaultValue(false)]
    public new bool AllowUserToAddRows { get { return base.AllowUserToAddRows; } set { base.AllowUserToAddRows = value; } }
    [DefaultValue(false)]
    public new bool AllowUserToDeleteRows { get { return base.AllowUserToDeleteRows; } set { base.AllowUserToDeleteRows = value; } }
    [DefaultValue(false)]
    public new bool AllowUserToOrderColumns { get { return base.AllowUserToOrderColumns; } set { base.AllowUserToOrderColumns = value; } }
    [DefaultValue(false)]
    public new bool AllowUserToResizeColumns { get { return base.AllowUserToResizeColumns; } set { base.AllowUserToResizeColumns = value; } }
    [DefaultValue(false)]
    public new bool AllowUserToResizeRows { get { return base.AllowUserToResizeRows; } set { base.AllowUserToResizeRows = value; } }
    [DefaultValue(BorderStyle.None)]
    public new BorderStyle BorderStyle { get { return base.BorderStyle; } set { base.BorderStyle = value; } }
    [DefaultValue(true)]
    public new bool ReadOnly { get { return base.ReadOnly; } set { base.ReadOnly = value; } }
    [DefaultValue(DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect)]
    public new DataGridViewSelectionMode SelectionMode { get { return base.SelectionMode; } set { base.SelectionMode = value; } }

    public CustomGridView()
    {
        AllowUserToAddRows = false;
        AllowUserToDeleteRows = false;
        AllowUserToOrderColumns = false;
        AllowUserToResizeColumns = false;
        AllowUserToResizeRows = false;
        BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
        ReadOnly = true;
        SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
    }
}
```

According to clearpath's post, this class creates a new control with overriding for some properties.

In this way you can change the default value of the DataGridView properties to any of the possible values so that we do not have to set them every time the control is used.

Use **new** to hide the original and **base** to link directly to that property, then add your default value over the property.

The constructor is needed to force the values when creating the component.

To use it from the editor it is necessary to compile the code previously.

Comment: Can you explain this class, why it answer and why it should be working ? It's to help future guy

Answer (score 4):

Let's say that you want to change `AllowUserToAddRows` to be `false` by default. You need to

- introduce `AllowUserToAddRows` as an override of the base property. Just delegate get and set calls to base implementation
- add `[DefaultValue(false)]` as an attribute of the property
- set the property to false in `MyDataGridView` constructor